# How can I globally restrict OpenSSL from SSL and TLS < 1.2, on Linux?

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, tls

I've been asked to disable the use of all SSL, and TLS < TLS 1.2, globally on one of my Centos boxes. Its been suggested that I should be able to do this in the openssl library.

I'm reasonably familiar with SSL/TLS, ciphersuites, etc, but I can't see how to do this in openssl.cnf. The documentation I find is clear on how to do this for Apache, or how to limit available protocol version within an application, but that's not what I'm after. I'm not running a web server.

Short of modifying the source to filter ciphersuites and protocols, then rebuilding, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`openssl.cnf` only configures some of the command line tools used to generate and manage certificates.  As such, it does nothing for the underlying library.

You say:

> I'm not running a web server

What are you running, which causes concern?  If you're running nothing, then you have nothing to worry about.  If you are running something, then configure that application not to use those protocols or cipher suites.

Also bear in mind that not all applications use OpenSSL for these functions - some may use GnuTLS [or others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptography_libraries).

You're correct - short of patching the source there is no way to disable these protocols globally.